# Dropdown in parent div with overflow:auto

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, overflow, dropdown

For a project, i need to create a view where a drop down menu is at the bottom of a parent div. A short fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Gruck/6owhaa63/, where "move to" item opens some more options, as shown on this mockup
[image: mock for that view]

```
  <div class="job">
    <div class="job-main">

      <div class="title">
        some content
      </div>
      <div class="counters">
        some other content

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="ops">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">visualize</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">move to</a>
          <ul class="move-to">
            <li>folder a</li>
            <li>folder b</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And some css

```
.job {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: auto;
}

.job-main {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
  width: calc(100% - 390px);
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding:10px;

  background-color: #EE0000;
}

.counters {
  width: 362px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  float: right;

  background-color: #00EE00;
}
```

How to get the options to be displayed on top of the parent div ? is there anyway to do so yet keeping the options inside the div ?

I guess i would have to move the options to outside the parent div and mannualy position them, but i would like to make sure i don't miss a nicer way to do so.

Thanks for any idea you might offer :)
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do it keeping it in the parent div is to adjust it's height so the list items will be visible.

if you change it to be outside the parent div, it still seems to layout correctly in the fiddle:

```
<div class="job">
  <div class="job-main">

    <div class="title">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="counters">
      some other content

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<div class="ops">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">visualize</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">move to</a>
      <ul class="move-to">
        <li>folder a</li>
        <li>folder b</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6owhaa63/2/